# Create elmah table and stored procedures when application starts

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah.mvc

I'm able to create the elmah table and stored procedures using the script:

https://code.google.com/p/elmah/downloads/list

Using the SQL Server Management Studio. And it woks fine.

But I would like to be able to create that table and stored procedures from the code. Where and how should I do that?

Comment: @X.L.Ant Sorry about that :)

Comment: I suppose you just have to add some code in your global.asax file, checking SP existence in DB and creating them if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I'm using Entity Framwork Migrations, I'm runing it from the `Up()` method in my inicial migration (Downloaded `ELMAH-1.2-db-SQLServer.sql` file):

```
 public override void Up()
 {
        string[] ElmahCommands = GetElmahStructureScript();
        foreach (string line in ElmahCommands)
        {
            Sql(line);
        }
        //...
}

public static string[] GetElmahStructureScript()
{
        string sqlConnectionString = new MyDbContext().Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
        Regex regex = new Regex("^GO", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        string[] lines = regex.Split(ElmahScript);
        return lines;
}

static string ElmahScript = @"
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ELMAH_Error] ...
...
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON";
```

**Atention**: Remove the last "GO" statement! (I also removed the first part of the script, to check the compatibility version...)